# Form Validation Exposes Variable Name insead of Label Name on the Altert Box - MM_validateForm()

Tags: php, javascript, html, webforms

[image]

As you see in the snapshot, variable names are shown e.g. "email_address", "email_message" and "email_subject". Instead i want to print "Email", "Message" and "Subject".

MM_validateForm() Javascript is used for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to try this.

1. Rename your input names, e.g. email_address => Email. This also means you need to rewrite some of your PHP, e.g. $_REQUEST['email_address'] => $_REQUEST['Email'];

A second way without doing a ton of rewriting you could do something like this add this function into your script tags:

```
function returnUserFriendlyLabel( nm )
{
      var val;
      switch( nm ) {
          case "email_address":
            val = 'Email';
            break;
          case "email_message":
            val = "Message";
            break;
          // etc.
          default:
            // just incase you missed a label
            alert( 'Unhandled label: ' + nm );

      }

      return val;
}
```

Then wherever you see this:

```
+nm+
```

You replace it with

```
+returnUserFriendlyLabel(nm)+
```